# accessing values in array after quiting the app

Tags: objective-c

In my iphone application I am storing values(string) in an array and I want to retrieve it when I reload the application.That is,When the user exits my app, I want this array to be saved so that when the app is loaded again by the user it want to be accessed

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting values in an array after exiting+objective c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893694/getting-values-in-an-array-after-exitingobjective-c)

Answer (score 0):

You cant save an array after an application has been closed.But this only "saves" when you press the home button(multitasking).

Im not sure as im an beginner in objective c also but i think you need to make an database in ur app so it saves the things needed to be saved for ur app.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the contents of the array are all property list objects (in your case they are as they are all NSString), you can save the array contents to a file using the

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

method on [NSArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html).

Then when the app is starting up again you can reinitialize the array from the file using :

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)aPath
```